# How to display only specific div with python webkit

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I got:

```
self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
self.scrolledwindow = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow")
self.scrolledwindow.add(self.webview)
self.webview.open(ADVSEARCHURI)
self.webview.show()
```

And it's displaying a whole site right, but i want to show only content's of specific div and hide the rest. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `execute_script` you can inject javascript into the webview. So just show or hide divs as you normally would:

```
js_code = "document.getElementById('foo').style.display = 'None';"
self.webview.execute_script(js_code)
```